# There is the possibility of the command np.empty generates a really large number instead of a very small one?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, empty-list

There is the possibility of the command np.empty from numpy to generate a very large number instead of a small one?

I'm asking this because I have a code that generates a empty list, and that list is updated in a given position of it if some condition are satisfied, if the condition is not satisfied, the code moves to another position of the list and don't changes the value from the first generated one.

But in the end of my simulation, when I check the list, I have some very small numbers, that are certainly the ones that came from the generation of the empty list, there is the numbers that got updated because the condition was satisfied, but there's also some very large numbers, that I have almost sure, that they aren't coming when the condition is satisfied, so I wonder if there is the possibility of they have come from the generation of the empty list.

Sorry if the problem may come from some miss of skill of mine, because I'm quite new in programming.

I Thanks for any possible help.

Here I create the empty list

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
%matplotlib inline


def valvula(jmin,jmax):

    y=np.empty(57)...
```

And here the list is updated

```
            if np.logical_and(r[i][0]>600,r[i][1]>=135):
                y[j-jmin]=r[i][0]
                break

            elif np.logical_and(r[i][0]>600,r[i][1]<=45):
                y[j-jmin]=r[i][0]
                break

            elif r[i][0]>=1099:
                break
```

Comment: `np.empty(57)` allocates memory but does not initialize it.  The values in that array will be whatever happened to already be in the memory that was allocated.  Only use `np.empty` if you are going to initialize that values in the array yourself.  Otherwise, use something like `np.zeros(57)` or some other function that initializes the values.

Comment: Don't use `np.empty` unless you intend to set every value yourself.